# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000070 Simple bean [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] class cannot be a non-static inner class

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee, glassfish

Добрый день!
Помогите понять причину - кейс такой:
Wicket + CDI + Glassfish4 + JEE7

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <wicket.core.version>7.1.0</wicket.core.version>
    <wicket.cdi.version>7.1.0</wicket.cdi.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>atbs-ui</finalName>
    <!--<directory>E:\projects\big_data\at-project-base-station\vagrant\app\containers\glassfish\webapps</directory>-->
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.atbs</groupId>
        <artifactId>atbs-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.atbs</groupId>
        <artifactId>atbs-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-cdi-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.cdi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

Часть класса MenuPanel

```
public class MenuPanel extends Panel {

    @Inject
    private MenuItemHelper menuItemHelper;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public MenuPanel(String componentId) {
        super(componentId);
        initListView();
    }

    private void initListView() {
        List<MenuCategory> menuCategoryList = menuItemHelper.createMenuItems();
        ListView<MenuCategory> contacts = new ListView<MenuCategory>("menuItems", menuCategoryList) {
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<MenuCategory> item) {
                item.add(new Label("menuItem", item.getModelObject().getLabel()));
            }
        };
        add(contacts);
    }
```

MenuItemHelper

```
public class MenuItemHelper {

    private static final String PAGE = "Page";

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ".";

    private static final String PAGE_PACKAGE = "ru.cs.vsu.wicket.pages";

    @Inject
    private MenuItemDao menuItemDao;

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public List<MenuCategory> createMenuItems() {
        List<MenuCategory> items = new ArrayList<MenuCategory>();
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = menuItemDao.listAll();
        Collections.sort(menuItems, new Comparator<MenuItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MenuItem o1, MenuItem o2) {
                return o1.getSortIndex().compareTo(o2.getSortIndex());
            }
        });
        for(MenuItem item : menuItems) {
            try {
                items.add(new MenuCategory(Model.of(item.getName()), getClassPage(item)));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                try {
                    logger.info(new String("Не удалось загрузить один из пунктов меню".getBytes("UTF-8")));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    logger.info(e.getMessage());
                }
                logger.info(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return items;
    }



    private Class<? extends Page> getClassPage(MenuItem item) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return (Class<Page>)Class.forName(PAGE_PACKAGE + SEPARATOR + item.getCode() + PAGE);
    }


}
```

MenuCategory

```
public class MenuCategory implements Serializable {
    private final IModel<String> label;
    private final Class<? extends Page> page;

    public MenuCategory(IModel<String>  textLabel, Class<? extends Page> page) {
        this.label = textLabel;
        this.page = page;
    }

    public IModel<String> getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public Class<? extends Page> getPage() {
        return page;
    }
}
```

При выполнении `initListView()` получаю вот это исключение:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000070 Simple bean [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl]  class  cannot be a non-static inner class

Что-то отдаленно похожее гуглил/видел - кто-то ссылался на cdi. Попробовал разные версии викета - проблема та же. Может мой код не верен?
Прошу помочь

Answer (score 1):

Может из-за этого `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000070 Simple bean [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] class cannot be a non-static inner class`, может нет, но так точно работать не может и вот почему.

Если Вы рассчитываете, что `menuItemHelper` в классе `MenuPanel` будет инициализировано с помощью CDI на момент самого первого использования этого поля, то Вы жестоко ошибаетесь.

Как мы видим, `menuItemHelper` используется в методе `initListView`, который вызывается из конструктора. Так вот, CDI заполняет поля только после отработки конструктора.  Так что при отсутствии других ошибок, Вы должны были бы получить NullPointerException.

Для того, чтобы провести инициализацию средствами CDI создаётся метод инициализации с аннотацией `@PostConstruct`. Тогда CDI выполнит его после вызова конструктора и инъекции зависимостей.

```
public class MenuPanel {
    @Inject
    private MenuItemHelper menuItemHelper;

    public MenuPanel() {
        // Здесь @Inject поля ещё не тронуты CDI
    }

    ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Здесь все @Inject поля уже заполнены CDI
    }

    ...
```

Другая ошибка в том, что CDI использует конструктор без параметров, которого для класса `MenuPanel` не наблюдается. Как при этом ругается CDI, даже не припомню.

Comment: Ответил ниже развернуто. Но вообще, смущает - а как вы будете id компонента передавать? если у Вас только конструктор по умолчанию. Да и инжект полей идет, а не самого MenuPanel. Вот с инициализацие полей CDI крайне не согласен, и дебаг тому подтверждение (и логирование тоже). У меня есть проект со старыми либами - и там похожие конструкции отрабатывают. В других классах текущего проекта есть же инжекты типа логирования, да даже в этом классе и все ок - все пишется - если например, я убираю ListView и вставляю обычные Label.  А здесь нет, и я пока не могу выявить разницу

Comment: Значит наверное wicket что-то мутит с cdi. Про wicket ничего не скажу, ибо не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

> Если Вы рассчитываете, что menuItemHelper в классе MenuPanel будет инициализировано с помощью CDI на момент самого первого использования этого поля, то Вы жестоко ошибаетесь.
>
> Как мы видим, menuItemHelper используется в методе initListView, который вызывается из конструктора. Так вот, CDI заполняет поля только после отработки конструктора. Так что при отсутствии других ошибок, Вы должны были бы получить NullPointerException.

По-моему, Вы жестоко ошибаетесь, подобная инициализация у меня используется более чем в одном приложении, и там нет никакого NPE - CDI отлично все инициализирует в нужный момент. Даже здесь я проходился дебагером - я получаю все пункты меню и menuItemHelper - инициализирован и работоспособен.

Теперь другой момент

> Другая ошибка в том, что CDI использует конструктор без параметров, которого для класса MenuPanel не наблюдается. Как при этом ругается CDI, даже не припомню.

Почему CDI лезет к MenuPanel??? я же не использую инъекцию для его создания - (создается в ручную - вызван конструктор)

```
public abstract class BasePage extends WebPage {


  protected HeaderPanel headerPanel;
  protected FooterPanel footerPanel;
  protected MenuPanel menuPanel;

  protected BasePage() {
    super();
    initBasePage();

  }

  protected final void initBasePage() {
    add(headerPanel = new HeaderPanel("headerPanel"));
    add(menuPanel = new MenuPanel("menuPanel"));
    add(footerPanel = new FooterPanel("footerPanel"));
  }
}
```

Инъекция проходит внутри панели.
Получается либо ошибка в другом, либо  не понятно - почему контейнер хочет так создавать MenuPanel